# MongoDB>DataNucleus>JPA Query using “ORDER BY” not working

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, jpql, datanucleus

I use either this query:

```
Query query = manager.createQuery("SELECT msg FROM Message msg WHERE msg.chat = :chat ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC");
query.setParameter("chat", chat);
```

or this query:

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = manager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Message> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Message.class);
Root<Message> msgRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Message.class);

Expression<Chat> chatExpression = msgRoot.get("chat");
ParameterExpression<Chat> chatParameter = criteriaBuilder.parameter(Chat.class);
Predicate belongsToChat = criteriaBuilder.equal(chatParameter, chatExpression);
criteriaQuery.where(belongsToChat);

TypedQuery query = manager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);

query.setParameter(chatParameter, this);
```

where `Message` got

```
@Getter
@Setter
private long timestamp;
```

so that I would guess I would get all Messages for this chat, but no I do not. I only do, when removing the `ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC` part. Neither `ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC` nor `ORDER BY msg.timestamp ASC` nor `ORDER BY msg.timestamp` work.

I hope my problem is well enough explained, because the only thing I have to add is my log file:

```
DEBUG Cache - Object "beans.Chat@f4ce6b" (id="beans.Chat:51") taken from Level 1 cache (loadedFlags="[YY]") [cache size = 5]
DEBUG Query - JPQL Single-String with "SELECT msg FROM Message msg WHERE msg.chat = :chat ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC"
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT msg FROM Message msg WHERE msg.chat = :chat ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC"
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Compile Time = 7 ms
DEBUG Query - QueryCompilation:
  [from:ClassExpression(alias=msg)]
  [filter:DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{msg.chat}  =  ParameterExpression{chat}}]
  [ordering:OrderExpression{PrimaryExpression{msg.timestamp} descending}]
  [symbols: msg type=beans.Message, chat type=beans.Chat]
DEBUG Connection - Created DB from MongoClient
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@dfdf24 [conn=com.mongodb.DB@16e62fc, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is starting
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@dfdf24 [conn=com.mongodb.DB@16e62fc, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] is committing
DEBUG Connection - ManagedConnection org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl@dfdf24 [conn=com.mongodb.DB@16e62fc, commitOnRelease=true, closeOnRelease=true, closeOnTxnEnd=false] committed connection
DEBUG Query - JPQL Query : Compiling "SELECT msg FROM Message msg WHERE msg.chat = :chat ORDER BY msg.timestamp DESC" for datastore
WARN  Query - FROM clause will be ignored. Not supported for this datastore (MongoDB doesn't do 'joins')
DEBUG Query - Compilation of filter to be evaluated completely in-datastore was impossible : 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.getFieldNameForPrimary(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:756)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.processPrimaryExpression(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:453)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compilePrimaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:193)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileUnaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:182)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileAdditiveMultiplicativeExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:161)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileRelationalExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:136)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileOrAndExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:78)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:46)
    at org.datanucleus.query.expression.Expression.evaluate(Expression.java:338)
    at org.datanucleus.query.expression.DyadicExpression.evaluate(DyadicExpression.java:69)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.compileFilter(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:176)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.compile(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:152)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JPQLQuery.java:400)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery.compileInternal(JPQLQuery.java:213)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1816)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1762)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:202)
    ...
WARN  ServletHandler
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.getFieldNameForPrimary(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:756)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.processPrimaryExpression(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:453)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compilePrimaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:193)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileUnaryExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:182)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileAdditiveMultiplicativeExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:161)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileRelationalExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:136)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.compileOrAndExpression(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:78)
    at org.datanucleus.query.evaluator.AbstractExpressionEvaluator.evaluate(AbstractExpressionEvaluator.java:46)
    at org.datanucleus.query.expression.Expression.evaluate(Expression.java:338)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.compileOrdering(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:250)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.QueryToMongoDBMapper.compile(QueryToMongoDBMapper.java:162)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery.compileQueryFull(JPQLQuery.java:400)
    at org.datanucleus.store.mongodb.query.JPQLQuery.compileInternal(JPQLQuery.java:213)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeQuery(Query.java:1816)
    at org.datanucleus.store.query.Query.executeWithMap(Query.java:1762)
    at org.datanucleus.api.jpa.JPAQuery.getResultList(JPAQuery.java:202)
    ...
```

Comment: Firstly any NPE is a bug. Secondly looking at the source code for that class where it happens you clearly are not using recent code so suggest you get a recent version and try that. Thirdly, if it happens with their current code then you raise a bug and provide them with a way to reproduce it. Fourthly, and better still you get the code and work out the fix if it is still happening, and then contribute it.

Comment: @NeilStockton, thank you, now I am using the newest datanucleus version (_[5.0,5.1)_), but still NPEs are thrown. I will have a look at the source code, but most likly will raise a bug. Anyway, thank you for your comment.